# Como imprimir uma mensagem dizendo que o elemento procurado não foi encontrado em lista? Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, lista

Olá, pessoal! Como faço para imprimir na tela uma mensagem dizendo que a entrada do teclado não consta na lista? Obs: Se a entrada do teclado constar na lista (por exemplo se o usuário digitar 'password'), o programa deve imprimir a posição do elemento na lista.
Eu pensei em adicionar um 'else' depois do 'if' só que assim o programa vai imprimir a mensagem dizendo que o elemento não consta na lista para cada verificação, ou seja, ele vai imprimir vários "Não consta" a cada vez que ele verificar que o elemento não está na lista, mas eu quero que ele imprima apenas uma vez essa mensagem.

Segue o código:

```
senhas_comuns = ['qwerty', 'password', 'google', 'starwars', 'mrrobot', 'anonymous', 'mypassword', 'minhasenha', 'senha', 'admin', 'abcd', 'master', 'batman', 'superman', 'dragonball']
print('Vamos ver se você consegue acertar alguma das senhas mais usadas sem números.')
entrada = input('Chute: ')

#marcador da posição.
posicao = -1
for cadaSenha in senhas_comuns:
posicao += 1
if entrada == cadaSenha:
    print('Você acertou! A senha ' + entrada + ' está na posição ' + str(posicao) + ' da lista.')
```

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia fazer tudo de um jeito bem mais sucinto, veja:

```
senhas_comuns = ['qwerty', 'password', 'google', 'starwars', 'mrrobot', 'anonymous', 'mypassword', 'minhasenha', 'senha', 'admin', 'abcd', 'master', 'batman', 'superman', 'dragonball']
print('Vamos ver se você consegue acertar alguma das senhas mais usadas sem números.')
entrada = input('Chute: ')

if entrada in senhas_comuns:
    posicao = senhas_comuns.index(entrada)
    print('Você acertou! A senha ' + entrada + ' está na posição ' + str(posicao) + ' da lista.')
else:
    print('Você errou')
```

Eu usei o operador "in" da linguagem para verificar se um determinado elemento pertence à lista. Se pertencer, uso a função "index" das listas para pegar o índice em que o elemento se encontra.